# to display JSON file in angularjs

Tags: node.js, json, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

i have a json file from the backend and I want to display it via `ng-repeat`. I do not know how to get the element.

In the html file, I want to do something like this

```html
<div ng-repeat = "answer in answers">
  {{answer}}
</div>
```

on my app.js file, I know I am getting the right data as I have displayed it on the console.log

```
socket.on('got message', function(data){
  console.log(data);
});
```

but I do not know how to convert the data to answer. the data on the console.log showed the following, if I expand it, how I get  them into `{{answer}}`

```
 Global Quote:
    01. symbol: "MSFT"
    02. open: "186.9500"
    03. high: "187.2500"
    04. low: "185.8520"
    05. price: "186.6900"
    06. volume: "5185159"
    07. latest trading day: "2020-02-20"
    08. previous close: "187.2800"
    09. change: "-0.5900"
    10. change percent: "-0.3150%"
```

I do not have to use socket, it is a local JSON file, only if I know how to read it into `{{answer}}`.

```
{ "Global Quote":{
    "01. symbol":"MSFT",
    "02. open":"186.9500",
    "03. high":"187.2500",
    "04. low":"185.8520",
    "05. price":"186.2950",
    "06. volume":"5758297",
    "07. latest trading day":"2020-02-20",
    "08. previous close":"187.2800",
    "09. change":"-0.9850",
    "10. change percent":"-0.5260%"
    }
}
```

---

But I am not sure how to pass the data from `app.js` to the html file. In my `app.js` file, I have

```
 socket.on('got message', function(data){
     $scope.answers = new Array;
     $scope.answers = data;
     console.log($scope.answers);
 });
```

but `$scope.answers` is passing to the html file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One approach is:

```html
<div ng-repeat="(key, value) in answers['Global Quote']">
    {{key}} : {{value}}
</div>
```

For more information, see

- [AngularJS ng-repeat Directive API Reference - Usage](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat#usage)

---

### UPDATE

AngularJS modifies the normal JavaScript flow by providing its own event processing loop. This splits the JavaScript into classical and AngularJS execution context. Only operations which are applied in the AngularJS execution context will benefit from AngularJS data-binding, exception handling, property watching, etc.

You can also use [$apply()](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$apply) to enter the AngularJS execution context from JavaScript:

```
socket.on('got message', function(data){
    $scope.$apply(function() {       
        $scope.answers = data;
        console.log($scope.answers);
    });
});
```

Keep in mind that in most places (controllers, services) [$apply](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$apply) has already been called for you by the directive which is handling the event. An explicit call to `$apply` is needed only when **implementing custom event callbacks,** or when working with third-party library callbacks.

[image]

For more information, see

- [AngularJS Developer Guide - Integration with the browser event loop](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/scope#integration-with-the-browser-event-loop)

Comment: Thanks @georgeawg, But I am not sure how to pass the data from app.js to the html file. In my app.js file, I have                                                                                            
        socket.on('got message', function(data){
     $scope.answers = new Array;
     $scope.answers = data;
     console.log($scope.answers);
        });   but $scope.answers is passing to the html file

Comment: thank you for the explanation, it is very clear. But for some reasons it did not work. I ended up using the solution from David Söderberg

Answer (score 1):

Referring to your comment on earlier answer, in the Model, View Controller design, your $scope.answer written on the controller makes it automatically available to the corresponding view, more explicitly, an html which has, ng-controller="YourCtrl", will have all the variables written inside $scope of YourCtrl.

One good way to display json is given in earlier answer. If u don't exactly know the structure of json, u can use this as well.

```
<pre>{{answer | json}}</pre>
```

Here json is an angular filter to display json data.

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
<head>
<title>My website</title>
</head>
<body>
<div ng-repeat="answer in answers">
    <p>{{answer}}</p>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```